# Drop-down menu in relational databases

Tags: mysql, attributes, relational-database, entity, entity-relationship

I'm just new to relational databases, and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around some aspects of them. One of the things that is confusing me may be very simple, but it is the prospect of drop-down menus. (Context: reverse-engineering a hotel website database)

If a site lists 'cities' in a drop-down menu, does that mean that 'cities' is an entity? I have asked classmates and they believe that yes, it is, and that each city should also be assigned a 'city ID'.I am, however, confused as I thought it would be an attribute since it can't be split further down in this context.

Am I misunderstanding how entities and attributes work? If so, can someone explain it to me further?

Answer (score 1):

`Cities` should most likely be an entity set. It could be implemented as a value set (for use in attributes) if you only cared about the name, but we often want to keep other facts about cities - which country/region they're in, suburbs, localized names, and so on. In addition, names can change and aren't necessarily unique or compact.

It's common practice in database design and maintenance to raise value sets to entity sets (which also means an attribute becomes a relationship) as requirements change or become clear. The opposite happens as well but less frequently.

When to make something a value set:

- When it represents a label or measurement
- When the values are meaningful in their own right

When to make something an entity set:

- When it has multiple non-prime attributes
- When it's involved in more complicated relationships than "whatever-to-one-city".
- When the number of elements are likely to change

These are just pointers, not hard rules.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that helped clear some things up! I think I have made some more sense of it all now.